# LTI-properties of a system summing infinite number of input values

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems

A pop-quiz featured a system analysis of the following system:
$y[n]=\sum_{n=0} ^{-\infty} x[n]$

The professor argued that this system exhibits the following properties:

- Linearity
- Causality
- Instability
- Memory
- Time-invariance

In general the system seems nonsensical, as it sums all samples from the beginning of time up until now, even though these are not accessible to $x[n]$. <del>Colleagues argued that the index $n$ might be "local" to the sum, translating to a more sensical description $y[n]=\sum_{k=0} ^{-\infty} x[n+k]$ with a distinguished index $k$.</del>

*EDIT:*
As provided by the answer below, the most likely meant system is $y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty} ^{n} x[k]$

*Note:*
*We do not intend to use dsp.stackexchange as a lazy solution but as a source of discussion, as this topic is of personal curiosity.*

Comment: If you're doing theoretical analysis, it's fair to claim knowledge of $x[n]\ \forall \ n \in (-\infty, 0]$.  _That's_ not the problem.  However, if you look at the expression given, you'll see that it sums from $k = -\infty$ up to $k = 0$ (variable change mine) _regardless of the current time_.  So it's just a constant.

Comment: For that matter, for _really_ theoretical analysis, you can claim knowledge of $x[n]$ for all time -- it really depends on the nature of the analysis you're doing.  E.g., Fourier transforms assume that a signal is known for all time, even though that's physically impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given equation relating the output to the input doesn't make sense. Note that on the left-hand-side the variable $n$ is used as time (or anything else) index, but on the right-hand-side it is used as the summation index. What is *probably* meant is the following system:

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^nx[k]\tag{1}$$

which is just an accumulator, and which has all the properties listed in the question.

Note that $(1)$ can be implemented recursively:

$$y[n]=y[n-1]+x[n]\tag{2}$$

The system's impulse response is the unit step sequence: $h[n]=u[n]$. It is straightforward to show that $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$y[n]=(x\star h)[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[k]h[n-k]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[k]u[n-k]\tag{3}$$